# sharing pledges between contacts

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, pledges, civipledge

In the user workflow I currently have, parents sign up for tuition payment plans for the program their children are attending. These are processed as pledges with varying numbers of installments, attached to the parent contact. Is there any way for me to assign those pledges to multiple people? For example in a two parent household, I would like both to get reminder emails. I feel like this is somewhat similar to giving soft credits to household members for contributions, but I'm not sure how to do it for pledges as well. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to assign a pledge to multiple contacts.

In the CiviCRM database, the pledge is assigned to a contact, but the individual pledge payment/installment is related to the pledge and not the contact.

Without a customization, this would not be possible.  Sorry

Comment: Bummer! Thanks for answering my question though. I will look into customization, though it may be above my skill level to do that.